# Define custom model names for Scaffold-DbContext reverse engineering

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, scaffolding, ef-core-2.1

I'm using `Scaffold-DbContext` to reverse engineer existing database. I'm specifying my custom `ContextDir`, `Context` and folder name for entities. I also use `-DataAnnotations`.  Here is the command I'm using:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "{connection_string}" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Entities -ContextDir DbContexts -Context TestContext -Tables "tableA", "tableB", "tableC" -DataAnnotations -Force
```

It works well, BUT.. in terms of model names, I'm limited to only two options:

1. Use `-UseDatabaseNames` flag, and `Scaffold-DbContext` will create table and column names exactly as they appear in the database (so "tableA" in my example).
2. Ommit `-UseDatabaseNames` flag, and database names are changed to more closely conform to C# name style conventions (so "TableA" in my example).

**What I'm looking for?** I'm looking for a third option. I'd like to be able to explicitly name them, one by one. For example:

```
-Tables "tableA" as "CustomTableA", "tableB" as "CustomTableB"
```

**Why do I need that? Here's a problem:** 
(scenario: in the future, Database will be changed and there are 4 new tables which I want to include in my models):

When I rename one for the models (after it was reverse engineered from db) today, and tomorrow I will run `Scaffold-DbContext` again to add new tables.. the changed model is still there. There's a lot of work, to do around that. So after first scaffolding, I'm forced to manually add models to my code. Being able to explicitly say what the names should be used, would be really great for big, corporate, legacy database projects.

Is there an option like that in `Scaffold-DbContext`? If not, is there a plan to add it? IF not, is there other tool that has such functionality?

BTW. In addition custom column/field names in these models, would be terrific too

Comment: I've worked with an equivalent of this command before (`dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold ...`) and I am pretty sure that this is currently not possible.

Comment: You can find how to do it using link https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28329. Just read the comments